# Android : orientation issue

Tags: android, android-layout

Issue !!!

I need to develop an application for tablet (v3.1) in both portrait and landscape orientation.

I have placed the resources:-
For Portrait - Images in "drawable" and Layouts in "layout"

For Landscape - Images in "drawable-large" and Layouts in "layout-large"

Issue is that the landscape layouts are not picking the right images.

Can someone please help?

Comment: create layout-land folder and copy paste your xml file.

Comment: layout: general layouts
layout-port: layout for portrait orientation
layout-land: layout for landscape orientation

Comment: @Android and appserv - I just renamed the folder "layout-large" as "layout-land", as you guyz said but it's not working. Can you please tell me what name should be given to the drawable folder for landscape images?

Comment: @Me-an-Droid folder name is layout-land and layout then check...

Comment: @Android - I had already tried it, and it's not working. What should be the name of drawable folder for landscape images?

Comment: @Me-an-Droid no need change drawable folder name...Portrait and landscape both image in one folder.

Comment: @Android - I will try this and let you know if it works for me. I hope it does. :(

Comment: @Android - Thanks buddy...this worked for me...I saved portrait and landscape images with different name in the only folder "drawable" and for layouts as u said. Please write your answer as a separate one so that I can accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Create two main.xml files for layout in both case: landscape and portrait.

2.Put those two main.xml in resources according to its type:

/res/layout-land/main.xml

/res/layout-port/main.xml

Just build and try your application GUI in runtime.

**or another example...**

create only "layout-land" folder and copy paste your xml file.

/res/layout/main.xml

/res/layout-land/main.xml

Comment: @Me-an-Droid  Most well come :)

Answer (score 1):

`layout-large` is for devices with large screens, and also we have for example `layout-small`. the folder you need is `layout-land`, that the "land" part stands for landscape.

Comment: Hi keyhan, I just tried with "layout-land" but it's still not working. It's still taking the portrait screen images in landscape mode.
The scrren size I am developing app for is : "1280 x 800".
Am I going somewhere wrong while defining name for the images folder for landscape as "drawable-large" ???

Comment: no, that's right' but be careful, if you have the folder `layout-large` and also `layout-land`, for large screen devices in landscape mode, `layout-large` will be applied, not `layout-land`! So, you have to use `layout-large-land` for for large screen devices in landscape mode. I hope it would help.

Answer (score 0):

I think your layout folder should be renamed as `layout-large-land` or simply `layout-land`

The below snap is from [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) document.
[image]